# How to make a dart page only appear once

Tags: dart, flutter, android-lifecycle

I have a signup page for my application and would love to only mkae it appear once after install. But the variables arent stored and one has to re-type everything

Comment: Noel, please consider providing more detail. It is nearly impossible to answer your question without a better understanding of how you have things coded. Consider providing a minimal case (show the code) associated with the challenge you are encountering.

Comment: If every time user opens the app and you want them to login, you can use `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(...) `

Answer (score 2):

You can Use `shared_preferences` or sqflite to store and retrieve the data into your flutter app;

you can use this plugins

**https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite**

Thanks you !